# How to code a variable that is not independent

Tags: r, statistics

How to code in R to get a variable called "error" that is not independent by first generating a vector of errors `error` and then returning a new vector `error2` whose first entry is `error[1]` but for `$i>1$` the `$i$-th` entry of `error2` is `error[i-1] + error[i]`.
Entries `error2` generated in this way are not independent.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
error <- runif(8)
error
[1] 0.8602515 0.3589546 0.8557547 0.4047402 0.9334315 0.4618969 0.6942308 0.3209568 
error2 <- cumsum(error)
error2
[1] 0.8602515 1.2192060 2.0749607 2.4797009 3.4131324 3.8750293 4.5692602 4.8902169
```

If you are interested in time series or autogression generally, there are many packages that may be helpful to you.

Comment: `error2[i] <- error[i] + error[i-1]` is that the `cumsum` of error?

Comment: Yes.  As demonstrated by the output in my answer.

Comment: I don't see it. Perhaps the question is worded ambigously. Your `error2[8]` should be the sum of `error[7]` and `error[8]` according to OP, yet your `error2[8]` clearly is not. the 7th and 8th element in `error` is 0.694... and 0.3209... the sum of which is not 4.890...

Answer (score 1):

dplyr's `lag` function will do away with some of the *i*-handling for you:

```r
error <- rnorm(10)
error2 <- error + lag( error, default=0 )

## check one sample:
stopifnot( error2[5] == error[5] + error[4] )
```